# Read-exec-write profiling for pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Although many data for the execution profiling can be obtained by Spark's REST API, is there any other way to get data for the overall execution of the application? How much time each task spends in the scheduler, how much time is needed for the data serialization?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Spark's documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#monitoring-and-instrumentation) you can enable Spark's profiler to output all the profiles to a desired folder. The snippet shows how to do it:

```
spark-submit --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true --conf spark.eventLog.dir=<path_to_directory>
```

In that file you can find information and timestamps for every event that occured durign the execution of a Spark application. If you search for `SparkListenerTaskEnd` you will be able to get information like the time the executor did to execute that specific task, as well as `serialization times`, `deserialization`, `Write result times`.